# Possible to assign PHP $_SESSION variable to javascript variable...?

Tags: javascript, php, session

I am making a game for my computing class. The user has to change settings of their robot before playing.

As the settings file where the user customises their robot is a separate PHP file I was wondering if there was a way to assign the $_SESSION variables to JavaScript variables like so:

`var tractionType = <?php echo $_SESSION['traction']; ?>;
...`

Is this possible?

Comment: Of course. Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: Compile that code, haha.

Comment: Should work fine, just remember to quote it if it's a string

Comment: That's it the quote. Forgot the quote... ;)

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can either create the whole JS file from PHP, as in

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/settings.php"></script>
```

or you put those variables inline

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var my_variable=<?=(int)$_SESSION['my_variable']?>;
</script>
```